# Why do I get this 'failed to load resource' error?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to create a chat app with socket.io and node.js.

Am following the tutorial from the socket.io website but I can't manage to get console log to show.

Here's my code:

index.js

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening to 3000'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
      }
      form {
        background: #000;
        padding: 3px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      form input {
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 90%;
        margin-right: 0.5%;
      }
      form button {
        width: 9%;
        background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
        border: none;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #messages {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #messages li {
        padding: 5px 10px;
      }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #eee;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

If I put this line ( const socket = io(); ) inside a script tag in .html it works. But not like I'm trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules/socket.io"));` to your code.

Then, load the script from /scripts/socket.io.js.
Hope this helps or leads you in the right direction.